A question from STEMS (by CMI) involving functions, divisors, and number theory
The question is:

Given $f ∶ N  \rightarrow N $ is a function satisfying $f(1) = 1$ and that for all n > 1 there are distinct
divisors $d_1$, $d_2$ of $n$ satisfying
                                   $n = f(d_1) + f(d_2)$
Find the sum of all possible values of $f(2023)$
And what I am getting is infinite solutions, this is how
lets take $n = p$ [where p is prime] 
Therefore n = $f(d_1) + f(d_2) = f(1) + f(p)$ 
$f(p) = p - 1$
now put $n = p * 2023$
therefore
$2023p = f(2023) + f(p)$
$2023p - (p-1) = f(2023)$
$2022p + 1 = f(2023)$ for every p = prime in Real positive
Thus I am not able to get a answer in integers, its answer is going till infinite
Please help me, and correct me where I am wrong

Could you provide a link to the STEMS paper?

Your error is in the step $2023p=f(2023)+f(p)$. The given statement tells us that for any $n$ there exist certain distinct divisors $d_1$ and $d_2$ such that $n=f(d_1)+f(d_2)$, not for all distinct divisors of $n$

https://cdn.tessellate.cmi.ac.in/stems/PastPapers/STEMS2024-Maths-CategoryA.pdf have this Soham Saha

Could you kindly provide the solution to this problem, as it appears to be unavailable across the entire internet?

@NamenotAllowed added an answer. Please comment if you need further clarification.

@SohamSaha Thanks for the Solution, its greatly made and I understood every part of it. Just a question for you that how you felt that in n = f(d1) + f(d2) one of the divisors d1 or d2 has to be n, like it was intuition or something else, by the way i have understood the entire proof

You're welcome. I like to try simpler test cases to get a feel for the problem, so tried finding values of $f$ for $1,2,3...$. Realised that there might be a pattern after getting the possible outputs of the function till $n=8$. (Btw, best of luck if you are trying for STEMS this year, I am participating too, from Category B) (also note that you can add comments below answers to directly respond to the answerer)

Thank you so much for your insights and the tip about adding comments! I truly appreciate it. Best of luck to you too for STEMS this year—let's both give it our best!

There was a logical error in my answer. Corrected now.

Convention: This answer assumes $\mathbb{N}$ to be the set of all positive integers.

Lemma 1: In $n=f(d_1)+f(d_2)$ for $n>1$, one of the divisors $d_1$ or $d_2$ has to be $n$
Proof:
Let’s take base case $n=2$, where we know that the statement is true.
Let us assume that the lemma holds for $2,3,…m-1$ (strong induction hypothesis)
If $m$ is prime, then the lemma holds.
For composite $m$, let there exist divisors $d_1$ and $d_2$ not equal to $m$ such that $m=f(d_1)+f(d_2)$.
Now, if $d_1=1$, then we have $f(d_1)=1=d_1$. If $d_1>1$, then we can apply the induction hypothesis on $d_1$ and infer that $d_1=f(d_1)+(\text{something in }\mathbb{N})>f(d_1)$. Thus, in general, we have $f(d_1)\leq d_1$
Repeating the same process on $d_2$, we get $$m=f(d_1)+f(d_2)\leq d_1+d_2$$
The maximum value of the distinct non-$m$ divisors of $m$ are $m/2$ and $m/3$, thus $m\leq m/2+m/3=5m/6$, which is clearly false. Thus, using proof by contradiction, our lemma is true even for composite $m$, which concludes our inductive proof.

Now, using the lemma, we have $n=f(n)+f(d)$ for $n>1$ and $d$ is a divisor of $n$ less than $n$.
Since STEMS is an open-book exam, I’d have used programming (as I am not good at calculations), but if you are confident enough, calculating for $2023$ can be done manually too:
$f(2023)=2023-f(\text{divisor of 2023})$.
We can iterate over the divisors and whenever we get a composite divisor, simply recurse through it in the same process. Ultimately collect all the values of $f(2023)$ obtained in a set and add them up.

How did you get that $f(d_1) + f(d_2) < d_1 + d_2$? Are you thinking of a different statement, since your lemma says nothing about $f(n) < n$?

Ah, you're using an immediate corollary of the lemma, that $n = f(n) + f(d) \Rightarrow f(n) \leq n$. Note that $\mathbb{N}$ typically includes $0$, so you might want to elaborate further.

@CalvinLin Actually in India, most elementary to undergrad courses assume $\mathbb{N}$ as starting from $1$, while the set of whole numbers starts from $0$.  While I am aware that this doesn’t apply worldwide, but I believe CMI uses this definition (as they have used it previously in some of their entrance exam papers too, I think). Edited my answer to clarify.

@CalvinLin I found that there was an error in my reasoning even after assuming $\mathbb{N}:=\mathbb{Z}^+$ and have corrected it now hopefully. Interestingly, I found the error when I was trying to formalize my proof in Lean as an exercise to learn the language
